# Changing background color in table when status is changed

Tags: webforms

I have table in VIEWS who stores from webform so i want to make is
When user select green from webform, then those informations need to be with green background, if other user select blue, that need to be blue in my table with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add use fields as classes to table rows and then through CSS assign background color to it. Check the screen shot, in the screen shot I have used a field as Row class. You will get your field replacement pattern in "Rewrite the output of this field" for all fields.

[image]